# "Jacobian is required for Newton-CG method" when doing a approximation to a Jacobian not being used when jac=False?

Tags: python, scipy

I'm doing an optimization with scipy.optimize.minimize, and attempting to use the following methods: 'Newton-CG', 'dogleg', and 'trust-ncg'. As I understand, for these methods a jacobian of the objective function is needed. However, the [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html) suggests that if jac is set to False, that the gradient will be computed numerically.

So I'm trying to call the function like so:

```
scipy.optimize.minimize(fun,x0,method='Newton-CG',jac=False,options={'disp':True}
```

When I call this, I get the following error message:

```
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/optimize.py", line 1351, in _minimize_newtoncg
raise ValueError('Jacobian is required for Newton-CG method')
```

That's surprising, since I thought I just set it to False (and this exception only occurs in */optimize.py if jac is set to None). So I go into /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/optimize.py and look at the function

```
def _minimize_newtoncg(fun, x0, args=(), jac=None, hess=None, hessp=None,
                   callback=None, xtol=1e-5, eps=_epsilon, maxiter=None,
                   disp=False, return_all=False,
                   **unknown_options):
```

At the beginning of this function I write the following print statements:

```
print (jac)
_check_unknown_options(unknown_options)
print(jac)
if jac is None:
    raise ValueError('Jacobian is required for Newton-CG method')
```

Surprisingly, 'None' is printed and not False! So I look at the calling function, which is in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/_minimize.py, and I find the code snippet that is setting this to None:

```
    if not callable(jac):
    if bool(jac):
        fun = MemoizeJac(fun)
        jac = fun.derivative
    else:
        jac = None
```

So that makes sense why jac is being set to None (though it seems incompatible with the documentation that suggests I'm going to get a numerical approximation to the jacobian by setting jac to False in the original function call).

What am I missing? Is it possible for me to call the 'Newton-CG' method like I'm doing above with Scipy computing the numerical approximation for the Jacobian for me?

Comment: a superficial scanning suggests that the approximation logic is missing in `_minimize_newton_cg`. So it is probably a bug in scipy's code base. Not perfectly sure, though. You may either want to open a bug in scipy's bug tracker at github, or hope that Warren Weckesser magically shows up :)

Comment: It can take several years for me to magically show up :)  This looks like a documentation issue.  After seeing [a new question related to this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51369984/jacobian-is-required-for-newton-cg-method-issue-still-exists-for-trust-ncg), I created an issue for it on github: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/9042

Answer (score 3):

Apparently the bug is still there, three years later.

For Newton-CG, the minimizer only takes a callable Jacobian. A quick way of obtaining one is to use `scipy.optimize.approx_fprime` as follows:

```
# x0 is your initial guess.
fprime = lambda x: optimize.approx_fprime(x, f, 0.01)
result = optimize.minimize(f, x0, method = 'Newton-CG', jac = fprime)
```

As my understanding this should be how "2-point" method is implemented.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my experience with SciPy...

The numerical approximation which SciPy documentation refers to is the "MemoizeJac" class that you see in the code you've cited. The memoization happens automatically when "jac" is not provided. It is likely a mistake in the documentation for the Newton-CG function that tells you to set the Jacobian to "False".

Simply set the jac=None or do not provide an argument for jac and a numerical approximation to the gradient will be used for the Newton-CG function.

Comment: *"Simply set the jac=None or do not provide an argument for jac ..."* Did you try this?  Which version of scipy did you use?  It doesn't work for me.

Comment: [version Scipy 0.19.1] I looked into it again, it's apparently a custom behavior for "Newton-CG" method. When using the default "method", the code works fine. However, when you only remove the "jac=False" then the error message says "Jacobian is required for Newton-CG method".  I'd have to look into it further to know why numerical approximations to the jacobian are not appropriate for the Newton-CG method, but for whatever reason they appear to be disabled.