# Is there a bug in scipy-0.18.1's `scipy.optimize.minimize`?

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, scipy

I am trying to solve for a function using specifically the dogleg method in [`scipy.optimize.minimize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html). To understand it better I am adapting an example at the bottom of the help page and using the dogleg method:

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize

def fun(x):
    return (x[0] - 1)**2 + (x[1] - 2.5)**2

# solver
res = minimize(fun, (2, 0), method='dogleg', jac=False) # or jac=None, it doesn't matter

print(res)
```

I get an error `ValueError: Jacobian is required for dogleg minimization.`

This is similar to an older problem: ["Jacobian is required for Newton-CG method" when doing a approximation to a Jacobian not being used when jac=False?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33926357/jacobian-is-required-for-newton-cg-method-when-doing-a-approximation-to-a-jaco) which doesn't appear to be resolved.

So my question: is there really a bug in this [`minimize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html) or am I not using it properly?

Comment: Note that Scipy and Python are two completely separate projects, with different release cycles and version numbers.  The question title suggests that you consider SciPy to be a part of Python 3.5, which it definitely is not.  Each release of Scipy can be used together with multiple Python versions, and the Scipy version number would be much more relevant to your question than the Python version number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must pass a Jacobian function to use the `dogleg` method, as it is a gradient-based optimization method. If you look at the `jac` argument of [`scipy.optimize.minimize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html) it says

> `jac` : *bool or callable, optional*
>   Jacobian (gradient) of objective function. Only for CG, BFGS, Newton-CG, L-BFGS-B, TNC, SLSQP, dogleg, trust-ncg. If `jac` is a Boolean and is `True`, `fun` is assumed to return the gradient along with the objective function. If `False`, the gradient will be estimated numerically. `jac` can also be a callable returning the gradient of the objective. In this case, it must accept the same arguments as `fun`.

Then if you look down at the Notes at the bottom of the page:

> Method dogleg uses the dog-leg trust-region algorithm for unconstrained minimization. **This algorithm requires the gradient and Hessian**; furthermore the Hessian is required to be positive definite.

Some gradient-based methods do not require an explicit Jacobian (and/or Hessian), as they will use a differencing method to approximate them. However `dogleg` *does* need you to explicitly pass such a function.

Comment: I agree that seems to be a feature that is not implemented rather than a bug.  However, my reading of the documentation is that the Jacobian will be numerically approximated when it is not provided explicitly.  It's prefectly possible to use the dog-leg trust-region optimizer with an numerically approximated Hessian.

Comment: @SvenMarnach That's my interpretation too. But what if I don't have a Jacobian/Hessian? Can I use say approx_fprime(https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.approx_fprime.html#scipy.optimize.approx_fprime) to calculate the Jacobian and simply parse this result into `jac`? Or do I need something fancier?

Comment: @MedullaOblongata How about just trying it?  For the example function you provided, it will definitely work, but in real-world applications it might depend on the specifics of the function you are trying to optimise.