# "Jacobian is required for Newton-CG method" issue still exists for trust-ncg

Tags: scipy, minimize

I am referering to the problem mentioned in ["Jacobian is required for Newton-CG method" when doing a approximation to a Jacobian not being used when jac=False?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33926357/6481544). I have ran into same problem (asking for jacobian for trust-ncg algorithm), but did not get the code to run. I tried `'2-point'`, and `False` but non of them worked.

Comment: I created an issue for this on the scipy github page: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/9042